# How do I assign unique instances as multiple keys to a dictionary in R?

Tags: r, dictionary, key, unique, instance

I have an R df where one column, assignment, looks like this:

| course | instance | assignment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A |
| 1 | 1 | B |
| 1 | 2 | B |
| 1 | 2 | C |
| 2 | 1 | A |
| 2 | 1 | C |
| 2 | 2 | B |
| 2 | 2 | A |

I need to create a superset (for lack of a better term) of all of the assignments in a course across instances.

For example: Course 1 was offered 2x, and in instance 1 it included assignments A and B, and in instance 2 it included assignments B and C. The superset of assignments in this class should include assignments A, B, and C each one time. In other words, every assignment that appears at least once across instances of a course should appear exactly one time in the superset.

UPDATE: I've tried the suggestion below.

```
library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(course) %>% 
summarise(all_assignments = toString(sort(unique(assignment))), 
.groups = "drop")
```

This returns the following:

| all_assignments | .groups |
| --- | --- |
| A | drop |

I've now tested this on the following sample data set:

```
df <- read.table(text = "course instance    assignment
1   1   A
1   1   B
1   2   B
1   2   C
2   1   A
2   1   C
2   2   B
2   2   A", header = T)
```

Which returns a similar structure:

| all_assignments | .groups |
| --- | --- |
| A, B, C | drop |

Apparently this exact code has worked for others, so I'm wondering what I'm doing incorrectly?

Comment: Can you please include your expected output. That will help us understood what you're after. For example, `library(tidyverse); df %>% group_by(course) %>% summarise(all_assignments = toString(sort(unique(assignment))), .groups = "drop")` returns a comma-separated string of assignments across all `instance`s for every `course`. Is that what you're after?

Comment: Yes, that's the basic idea. I tried your suggestion and updated the question with the output, which is a single row. I'm sure it's a small error I'm missing.

Comment: Please see below for a fully reproducible example. Make sure that your actual data matches your sample data, e.g. column names are exactly the same (R is case-sensitive).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear on your expected output (see my comment above); please have a look at the following

```r
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    group_by(course) %>% 
    summarise(
        all_assignments = toString(sort(unique(assignment))), 
        .groups = "drop")
## A tibble: 2 × 2
#  course all_assignments
#   <int> <chr>          
#1      1 A, B, C        
#2      2 A, B, C
```

This is tested & verified on `R_4.2.0` with `dplyr_1.0.9`.

---

### Sample data

```r
df <- read.table(text = "course instance    assignment
1   1   A
1   1   B
1   2   B
1   2   C
2   1   A
2   1   C
2   2   B
2   2   A", header = T)
```

Comment: Strange, I'm getting a similar output for the sample data, where the assignments are grouped, but not linked to a course (i.e. the column header is "all_assignments" and the first cell says "A, B, C", and the second column is ".groups" with a row cell that says "drop"). I'll play around with it a bit more. What does your output look like for the sample?

Comment: @briahnah Sorry but I don't know what you mean by *"where the assignments are grouped, but not linked to a course"*. The above works reproducibly for the sample data included (as per your main post). There should be no `.groups` column. First step is to verify on your end by copy & pasting data & code from my answer. If your actual data are different, please provide representative sample data otherwise it's difficult to help & debug.

Comment: Omg, it ended up being a package conflict. I notice that your original suggestion imports tidyverse, and your second suggestion imports dplyr, which was the confusion. I started a new image workspace and it seems to work fine now. Thanks for the support!